# java JList adding elements to model is changing visibleRowCount

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am using the default JList model for adding elements to a JList. Occasionally when I would add an element to the model it would change the JLists visibleRowCount from 2 to 1. It does not seem to matter weather I add one or 10 elements, it keeps changing it to only 1 visible row even if I try to force it back after adding elements. I am using a panel with a flowlayout to hold the Jlist and its scroll with that panel in a gridBagLayout

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Is your question *"How to X?"*?  If so, add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30355285/edit).  If not, think of a specific question and do the same (edit).

Comment: I have never seen this happen. It seems to me like you are creating a new JList, intead of updating/replacing the ListModel.